# C# .NET query in MultiSelectList doesn't work

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a webmail like project with c#. I have a MultiSelectList in which I am trying to select all the groups that the logged in user is a member of so that the user can pick these and send messages to them, but the user is not supposed to get groups that they aren't part of.

These are my models:

```
public class Group
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime LastLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public int DeletedMessages { get; set; }
    public int LoginCount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the MultiSelectList with the query:

```
ViewData["ToGroupName"] = new MultiSelectList(_context.Group.Where(group => 
group.Users.Where(user => user.UserId.Contains(currentUserID))
.Select(s => s.GroupId).FirstOrDefault() == group.ID), "ID", "Name");
```

I use ApplicationDbContext with DbSets<> to select items from the database. The thing I don't understand is that I use this exact same query in another part of the code to get all groups that the user is part of, but for some reason it doesn't work here. Instead it selects all the groups that are in the database regardless of if you are a member or not.

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: It is possible that `Contains()` is returning more than one user id, e.g. you look for user "100" and returns "98100", "51009", etc. because user id is a string. Then this `FirstOrDefault()` is getting one of them. Consider using Equals or ==.

Comment: I actually had a hunch that this might be the case but sadly it didn't change anything :(

But thanks for the suggestion! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to do too much.. just check to see if the group has any user id's that match current user id..

you can use ANY

```
ViewData["ToGroupName"] = new MultiSelectList(_context.Group.Where(group =>  
    group.Users.Any(user => user.UserId == currentUserID)), "ID", "Name");
```

`Any` will return true if any item in the collection meets your criteria.  In this case, if any UserGroup in the Group's `ICollection<UserGroup> Users` has a `UserId == currentUserID`, then include that group in the result.

Comment: I'm pretty new to c# .NET and I've had quite the trouble understanding these queries. Thank you for the improved query, this one is so much easier to understand than the one I made. This query did work on another part of the code where I try to do the exact same thing, but it didn't work for the MultiSelectList. I'm starting to believe that it's not the query that is wrong, but there is something else that is acting weird.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I managed to find the problem and it is now solved, thank you for the help! :)